# D3 button click transition not working

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, interactive

I have rendered a map India.json using d3. I want to create a button which will render a different map India_simple.json on click. Unfortunately the click button does not seem to work. Code is as follows -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Set a style for our worldshape-data -->
  <style>
  path {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    fill: grey;
  }
  </style>
<body>
  <div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton" 
                 type="button" 
                value="Update" 
                onclick="updateData()" />
  </div>
  <!-- implementation of the hosted D3- and TopoJson js-libraries -->
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

  <!-- map creation --> 
  <script>
  // canvas resolution
  var width = 1000,
      height = 600;

  // projection-settings for mercator    
  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      // where to center the map in degrees
      .center([100, 30 ])
      // zoomlevel
      .scale(700)
      // map-rotation
      .rotate([0,0]);

  // defines "svg" as data type and "make canvas" command
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // defines "path" as return of geographic features
  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  // group the svg layers 
  var g = svg.append("g");

  // load data and display the map on the canvas with country geometries
 d3.json("india.json", function(topology) {
    g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.collection)
            .geometries)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)

});

function updateData() {
d3.json("india_simple.json", function(topology) {
    g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.collection)
            .geometries)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path);


});
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no error in the console. Only the first map is displayed and nothing happens on clicking the button. I have shared the two json files here in dropbox - [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wrxyngyq4jdie9c/AACG2-dTzC79rRvlxlOC5poBa?dl=0](http://dropbox)

Also tried deleting the existing svg, and replacing it with a new svg. But this code only appends new svgs, does not replace. The updateData code -

```
function updateData() {
  d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // defines "path" as return of geographic features
  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  // group the svg layers 
  var g = svg.append("g");

d3.json("json.india_simple", function(topology) {
    g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.collection)
            .geometries)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path);


});
```

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - Done. Still doesnt work

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - Thanks for the tip! But Im sure it works with the parenthesis too. In updateData function, I tried to delete the svg on button click and create a new svg. But on implementing this, the button click did not delete the original svg but created the new svg. And it keeps creating new svgs as long as you keep clicking that button

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - Appended the updateData() code to the bottom of the question for your reference

Comment: Try just `d3.select("svg").remove();`. Alternatively, using `svg > *`, don't append the SVG again.

Comment: Using 'd3.selectAll("svg").remove();' does not clear the existing svg. 'd3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();' clears the existing svg, but the new svg is created below the deleted svg. Eitherway, the problem is not solved. How do I replace the svg instead of appending it?

Comment: Keep `d3.selectAll("svg > *")` and then use `var svg = d3.select("svg");`.

Comment: 'var svg = d3.select("svg");' did not work, but i tried 'var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg") and somehow it worked and I think this should be good for now. Thanks for your help @GerardoFurtado